# Firestore how can i get top-level collection inside documents list?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

example1) collection - doc - collection - doc - collection

example2) collection

example1 structure, I can import all the documents lists inside the last collection.

example2 structure, I can't get all the documents lists inside the collection.

how can i get top-level collection inside documents lists?

here is my code down here.

```
// this is example1. this is working!!
  dbService
    .collection("users")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection(uid)
    .doc("video")
    .collection(uid)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.map((doc, index) => {
        videoList.push(doc.data());
        console.log(doc.data());
      });
    });



// this is example2. this is not working !!!!!
  dbService
   .collection("users")
   .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.map((doc, index) => {
      videoList.push(doc.data());
      console.log(doc.data());
    });
  });
```

example2 is return empty array. why is this?

Comment: At first glance that second snippet looks fine to me. What isn't working about it? So: if you step through the code line by line in a debugger, which line is the first that doesn't do what you expect it to do? Be detailed and specific in your description of the problem, as it increases the chances someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Loading data from Firestore is shallow. This means that if you load documents from the `users` collection, no data from subcollections is automatically included.

---

If you want to load data from a specific user's `video` subcollection, you'll need to make an extra call:

```
  dbService
   .collection("users")
   .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.map((doc, index) => {
      if (/* this is a user you are interested in */) {
        snapshot.ref.collection(videos).get().then((videos) => {
          videos.forEach((video) => {
            videoList.push(video.data());
          })
          console.log(doc.data());
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

---

If you want to load all videos for all users you can use a so-called collection group query:

```
  dbService
   .collectionGroup("videos")
   .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.map((doc, index) => {
      videoList.push(doc.data());
      console.log(doc.data());
    });
  });
```

If you want to find the ID of the user for a specific video in here, you can find it with `doc.ref.parent.parent.id`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
What I want is to load all the documents inside the top collection, is this the same?
I did what you told me, but I'm not getting the results right.